# Why FullSimplify doesn't work when subscript included?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

This is OK.
[image: work ok]
FullSimplify[l[t] + r[t], {m[t] == l[t] + r[t]}]

But when I add a subscript to l, FullSimplify can not return the correct result. Is this a bug?
I will be grateful if anyone can give me some tips.
[image: work wrong]
FullSimplify[
 Subscript[l, 1][t] + r[t], {m[t] == Subscript[l, 1][t] + r[t]}]

Comment: Please post plain text code also.

Comment: try `FullSimplify[ Subscript[l, 1][t] + r[t], {z[t] == Subscript[l, 1][t] + r[t]}] /.  z -> m`?

Comment: In general, troubles like these are why one should just keep subscripts to formatting, and not for algebraic computations.

Comment: the problem is independent of  appearance of `Subscript` in the expressions. For example, compare `FullSimplify[k + r, {m == k + r}]` and `FullSimplify[v + r, {m == v + r}]`